# Bash PROMPT_COMMAND appears to be overriding vim's :set title

Tags: bash, vim, konsole

I'm using Konsole 18.04.3, on Fedora 28, and I have the following set in my `.bashrc`:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]30;$(basename $(pwd))\007"'
```

I have the following set in my `.vimrc`:

```
autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead,BufEnter * let &titlestring = expand("%:t") 
set title
```

As I understand it, this *should* cause vim to overwrite the directory name of the window with the name of the file I'm editing. However, that doesn't appear to be the case. When I launch vim, it's as if the `set title` command has no effect. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I found that using `printf` instead of `echo` solved the problem. Instead of

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033]30;$(basename $(pwd))\007"'
```

I now have

```
export PROMPT_COMMAND='printf "\033]0;%s\007" "$(basename $(pwd))"'
```